# Is it called a "device driver" if it is not pointing to a hardware device?

Tags: linux, terminology

The following diagram shows the relationship between a device file, a device driver, and a hardware device:

```
Application <---> /dev/device_file <---> device driver <---> hardware device
```

So the application writes data to the device file, and then the data gets passed to the device driver, and then the device driver passes the data to the hardware device (and the opposite happens when reading).

But there are device drivers in Linux that don't point to a hardware device, for example, the /dev/random device file points to a device driver that doesn't point to a hardware device:

```
Application <---> /dev/random <---> device driver
```

Is it accurate to say that /dev/random points to a "device driver", or is there another terminology to use?

Comment: These are called pseudo-devices on some systems.

Comment: When you read/write/ioctl the device file, you're calling into the driver program, which might operate the read hardware or calling some internal non-hardware-related  kernel function. The device node itself is simply an interface that kernel expose to you.

Answer (score 0):

Your model is not correct. The dev files are provided by `udev` (or in older Linux's `devfs`). Now `udev` is apart of `systemd`. None of this is required at all, you can use drivers with direct API calls (like in Windows). In fact, afaik, some systems don't build with it.

Create a file in `/dev` is just a function of whatever created `dev`. Checkout `mount | grep ' /dev '`

```
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=8087376k,nr_inodes=2021844,mode=755)
^ See the udev. That's what created the abstraction.
```

The driver exists in the kernel. The abstraction layers is provided so you have file/io to the device. This follows the Unix methodology that all things are files, but it's **not** required.

Comment: Device nodes are part of the kernel API, they’re not an external abstraction. Some drivers have equivalent system calls (*e.g.* [`getrandom()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrandom.2.html)) but most don’t.